# Applying group policies to another OU

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have an OU "***NewGroups***" in which I have a group called "***Group***". The members of that group may be in any **OU** in the domain. How to apply ***GPO*** to that NewGroups OU so that users from all the other ***OUs*** in the group "Group"  will be affected by the **GPO**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group Policies apply to Users and/or Computers, but not to Groups.  You cannot have Group Policy enumerate a list of users in a group that has a GPO applied so that the settings apply to users in the group (but that exist outside the GPO scope).

You will need to apply the GPO at the domain level if the users could reside in any OU and then Filter the policy to only apply to the needed group.  You can do this by adding the group to the `Security Filtering` section under the `Scope` tab when selecting the GPO in the Group Policy Management Console. You'll want to add the group you need the policy to apply to, and remove everything else.

Comment: Thank you @Cheekaleak . Can you also clear another doubt? i just wanna know why primary group is mandatory to the user? Why an user should have at least one primary group?